# Plugin management with plugins inside a plugin configuration section

Tags: maven, plugins, configuration, pom.xml, maven-bom

I have the following setup in my POM

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For `jaxb2-basics-annotate` and `jaxb2-basics` I set versions in the plugin management section of an imported BOM file. However, these versions apparently do not apply, because when I compile I keep getting error message that the versions of these two plugins are not set. So, is it that plugin management sections do not work with "nested" plugins in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plugins` section in your example is inside the `configuration` element of the maven-jaxb2-plugin. So it's just a configuration element that happens to be called 'plugins', and not the same element as

```
<build>
  <plugins>
```

Maven itself does not validate the elements inside a plugin's configuration, as it can't know which elements are legal and not. Hence, `pluginManagement` is not applied here.